# Azure Cognitive Search - Spell Checker Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I am looking for implementing spell checker for the azure cognitive search in C#. For now I have reviewed the spell checker link from the official Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/speller-how-to-add

But there's no code snippet or example that demonstrates the use in C#. The link does say we need to pass the parameters like "speller=lexicon" and "queryLanguage=en-us" with the search API call.

I have a basic search implemented for Azure Cognitive search. Please refer the below code snippet:

```
 // Configures the 'SearchParameters' object
        SearchParameters searchParams = new SearchParameters
        {
            Skip = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE,
            Top = PAGE_SIZE,
            IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
            Facets = Facets
        };

        // Returns all results on initial page load
        string searchString = "*";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            searchString = searchText;

        // Performs a search request on the specified Azure Search index with the configured 'SearchParameters' object
        DocumentSearchResult<Document> result = searchIndexClient.Documents.Search(searchString, searchParams);
```

But the "SearchParameters" have no properties of passing the "speller" and "queryLanguage" parameters to get the result for spell checker. Please review the screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone suggest for the "spell checker" for code implementation in C#?

Comment: From [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/speller-how-to-add), we can find:  *Spell correction is in public preview under supplemental terms of use. It's available through the Azure portal and preview REST API only.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the API for speller, it's "queryspeller" in the SDK. Here's the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchoptions.queryspeller?view=azure-dotnet-preview

I didn't find examples or tests for that API but here's the tests for searchoptions, and maybe it will give you enough to go on:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/tests/Models/SearchOptionsTests.cs

Also, I just noticed you're using the old deprecated library.  Can you use azure.search.documents instead?